# Syntax for jqAssistant / cypher - Return all paths that end in one node

Tags: syntax, cypher, jqassistant

I scanned my Java code base with jqassistant into a neo4j library, and I'd like to get all calls (also transitive) to a certain method `methodname`. I guess it something like this:

```
MATCH
  (c:Class)-[:DECLARES]-(m:Method)-[:INVOKES*0..]-
  (v:Method {signature: 'javax.path methodname(argument)'})
RETURN DISTINCT c.fqn, m.name, m.signature
```

Currently, it doesn't seem like the answer is really complete. I only get methods from the same class as `methodname`, where it is direct calls to the method.

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: The syntax looks correct to me but the relations should be directed. If you don't see all expected callers there might be issues regarding to either

1. Inheritance: If a caller invokes an abstract method in a super class the scanned graph will not contain relations to implementations of this method. 
2. Artifact boundaries: During scan invocations are only resolved between classes within the same artifact.

For both cases there are concepts (i.e. pre-defined queries) available that try to resolve relations. Are you scanning the CLI or Maven plugin?

Comment: Yep, tried it too and works like expected - at least after I made the lines to arrows, e.g. (c:Class)-[:DECLARES]->(m:Method)

Comment: @DirkMahler I have simplified the Syntax to `MATCH (m:Method)-[:INVOKES*0..]->(v:Method {signature: 'sig'}) RETURN [(m)-->(v)]` and that corrects indeed that one little mistake, but I assume the issue is more on the inheritence or artifact boundaries level. 

`./bin/jqassistant.sh scan -f ~/external/software/software-core/target/
./bin/jqassistant.sh scan -f ~/external/software/software-core/target/lib/`

How would I have to invoke it correctly?

Comment: Ok, you're using the CLI. Can you try to run "jqassistant.sh analyze -concepts classpath:Resolve", try your query again and see if the result has changed?

Comment: Nothing changed, but the command failed. So no surprise. The errors look all roughly like this: `[ Concept Application Failure ]` `2018-01-24 09:20:09.260 [main] WARN AbstractAnalyzeTask - Concept: classpath:ResolveImplements`

Comment: Hm, difficult... Did the command really fail (showing an execption) or were just warnings that concepts could not be applied? What do the scanned folders contain: Java classes or JAR/WAR files?

Comment: It was only warnings as shown above. The folders contained the jar files. I tried again with a clean setup, and instead of compiling the jars myself got myself the already built jars. It still never found more connections. Is INVOKE the right connection between two methods?

Comment: My bad, if I return the value from the question, I now get more. *ooff*, but not with `[(m)-->(v)]`. Also I am still surprised, how short the list is (since it is open ended, I would have expected to find the source at some point. What I do have is the sink function.

Comment: Those newly found methods, are more steps away, but are all from the same class. I hasn't found any method from another class calling those methods, calling `v`.